# HTML/CSS/JS issues with positioning text on top of background

Tags: javascript, html, css, header

I am using HTML CSS and JS to make a page on my website and when adding a logo and a menu as a header, the website does not work as intended. The text is supposed to be on top of the background and is supposed to be on the "overlay" class with is supposed to move to the side also when the menu icon is clicked. Also, the menu icon back ground has been removed and is supposed to be white. I don't know what I did wrong so any help will be appreciated! The bottom STYLE section is used for the menu and the header and the top STYLE code is used for the text I want to be displayed on top.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <section class="showcase">
   <script type="text/javascript">
   window.addEventListener('load', () => {
       const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');
       const showcase = document.querySelector('.showcase');

       menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
           menuToggle.classList.toggle('active');
           showcase.classList.toggle('active');
       })
   });
      </script>
  <header>
     <style>
        #uploadinfo {
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 00;
            color: #fff;
            line-height: 2em;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 1em;
            margin: 20px 0;
            max-width: 700px;
            text-align:center;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 45%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        #back
        {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 2.5em;
        background: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-top: 10px;
        color: #111;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        transition: 0.2s;
        justify-content: center;
        border: none;
        text-align:center;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 80%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        #back:hover
        {
        letter-spacing: 6px;
        }
        #email
        {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 2.5em;
        background: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-top: 10px;
        color: #111;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        transition: 0.2s;
        justify-content: center;
        border: none;
        text-align:center;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 90%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        #email:hover
        {
        letter-spacing: 6px;
        }
        #text {
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 300;
            color: #fff;
            line-height: 2em;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 1em;
            margin: 20px 0;
            max-width: 700px;
            text-align:center;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 52.5%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            z-index: 10;
        }
        #info {
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 800;
            color: #fff;
            line-height: 1em;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 3em;
            margin: 20px 0;
            max-width: 700px;
            text-align:center;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 12.5%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        #info2 {
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 800;
            color: #fff;
            line-height: 1em;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 3em;
            margin: 20px 0;
            max-width: 700px;
            text-align:center;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 27.5%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        #back
        {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 2.5em;
        background: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-top: 10px;
        color: #111;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        transition: 0.2s;
        justify-content: center;
        border: none;
        text-align:center;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 80%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        #back:hover
        {
        letter-spacing: 6px;
        }
        #email
        {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 2.5em;
        background: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-top: 10px;
        color: #111;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        transition: 0.2s;
        justify-content: center;
        border: none;
        text-align:center;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 90%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        #email:hover
        {
        letter-spacing: 6px;
        }

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
*
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
header
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 40px 100px;
 z-index: 1000;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
}
header .logo
{
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle
{
 position: relative;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 background: url(https://i.ibb.co/HrfVRcx/menu.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 30px;
 background-position: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle.active
{
 background: url(https://i.ibb.co/rt3HybH/close.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 25px;
 background-position: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.showcase
{
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 100vh;
 padding: 100px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 background: #011721;
 transition: 0.5s;
 z-index: 2;
}
.showcase.active
{
 right: 300px;
}

.showcase video
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
 opacity: 0.8;
}
.text
{
 z-index: 10;
}

.text h2
{
 font-size: 5em;
 font-weight: 800;
 color: #fff;
 line-height: 1em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 300px;
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
.menu ul
{
 position: relative;
}
.menu ul li
{
 list-style: none;
}
.menu ul li a
{
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #011721;
}
.menu ul li a:hover
{
 color: #03a9f4; 
}

@media (max-width: 991px)
{
 .showcase,
 .showcase header
 {
   padding: 40px;
 }
 .text h2
 {
   font-size: 3em;
 }
}
    </style>
    <h2 class="logo">LOGO HERE</h2>
    <div class="toggle"></div>
   </header>
   </div>
   </div>
 </section>
 <div class="menu">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="/signup">Sign Up</a></li>
     <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
     <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
    <div class='overlay'>
    <div class='text'>
        <p id='info'>Text</p>
        <p id='info2'>Text 2</p>
        <p id='uploadinfo'>Text 3</p>
        <a href="/login"><button id='back'>Login</button></a>
        <a href="mailto:EMAIL"><button id='email'>Button</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
    <body style="background-color: #011721;">
    </body>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you need remove duplicite body tag and adjustment close tag header, clean tags div empty also

This code work ok follow example solution

```js
 window.addEventListener('load', () => {
   const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');
   const showcase = document.querySelector('.showcase');

   menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
     menuToggle.classList.toggle('active');
     showcase.classList.toggle('active');
   })
 });
```

```css
#uploadinfo {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 00;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 20px 0;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 45%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#back {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  background: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #111;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  justify-content: center;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#back:hover {
  letter-spacing: 6px;
}

#email {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  background: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #111;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  justify-content: center;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 90%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#email:hover {
  letter-spacing: 6px;
}

#text {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 20px 0;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 52.5%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 10;
}

#info {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 20px 0;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 12.5%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#info2 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 20px 0;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 27.5%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#back {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  background: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #111;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  justify-content: center;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#back:hover {
  letter-spacing: 6px;
}

#email {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  background: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #111;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  justify-content: center;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 90%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#email:hover {
  letter-spacing: 6px;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

header .logo {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/HrfVRcx/menu.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle.active {
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/rt3HybH/close.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.showcase {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: #011721;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 2;
}

.showcase.active {
  right: 300px;
}

.showcase video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.text {
  z-index: 10;
}

.text h2 {
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu ul {
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #011721;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #03a9f4;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .showcase,
  .showcase header {
    padding: 40px;
  }
  .text h2 {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/signup">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section class="showcase">
  <header>
    <h2 class="logo">LOGO HERE</h2>
    <div class="toggle"></div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class='text'>
      <p id='info'>Text</p>
      <p id='info2'>Text 2</p>
      <p id='uploadinfo'>Text 3</p>
      <a href="/login"><button id='back'>Login</button></a>
      <a href="mailto:EMAIL"><button id='email'>Button</button></a>
    </div>
  </main>
</section>
```